# oauth2, imap, gmail - fetching mails - gmail api is down and can't find reference to oauth2

Tags: gmail, imap, oauth-2.0, gmail-imap

1. I have a requirement (flexible) to use oauth2. (existing architecture/code)

   1. I have a need to do some text manipulation of subscriber's email headers.

Solutions I've tried.

I've tried to download the sample code for java and it correctly connects to gmail's imap servers. It however responds with oath_version=1 and is expecting a password. I've tried to massage the code to change the params as other api's like their Contacts api oauth2 without success.

Question: 
(multipart)

1. Api is down:http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_migration/developers_guide_java.html any reference online would be ideal (it has been down for at least half a week since last week Wed). If you wondered - yes I did post on their forums before asking here for the updated link.
2. Is there a way to: a) make oauth2 request and b) Any (minimal) code exaples I can look at would be great.

Thanks in advance for reading this post.

Comment: http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_migration/developers_guide_protocol.html#Auth java, python & .net

Comment: @Ragetzaz: Thanks for the link. I must have not explained myself well. I want to implement an imap client with oauth2. Perhaps the link on my post is not even correct. The link you posted, I briefly looked at all the Email classes [link]http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/ there is no class specifying how to "read" from gmail server. Thanks.

Comment: does anyone have an insight ?

Comment: I was able to get a working example in Ruby. What language are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working, Ruby example of fetching email from Google using the OAuth2 protocol:

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, usessl = true, certs = nil, verify = false)
imap.authenticate('XOAUTH2', 'example@gmail.com', 'oauth2_access_token_goes_here')
imap.select('INBOX')
imap.search(['ALL']).each do |message_id|

    msg = imap.fetch(message_id,'RFC822')[0].attr['RFC822']
    mail = Mail.read_from_string msg

    puts mail.subject
    puts mail.text_part.body.to_s
    puts mail.html_part.body.to_s

end
```

Note: This example uses [ruby `mail` gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail) and [`gmail_xoauth` gem](https://github.com/nfo/gmail_xoauth), so you will need those installed for this code sample to work. I am also using the `omniauth` and `omniauth-google-oauth2` gems to handle logging the user in and using the access token.